# Get Access Token for a closed group on facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get an access token for a closed group so that i can display the group informaiton on my website, but unfourtunatly all the methods that i see to get an access token are for application which requires the appId and secret code. is there a way that i can get it for aa group cause it doesnt have the parameters specified on the doc.

Can some1 please help me out, i'm out of options.

Thanks
D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the user and friends permissions. There is a specific `user_groups` permission. Generally the way Facebook authentication works is that the authenticating user will allow your application or (website) access to what they themselves have access to. So if a user is a member of a particular group and allows your application to connect through the user_groups permission, then your application will have access to this group to.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: current api reference has a limitation on user_groups saying  _"This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission."_

Comment: "user_groups
This permission is only available for apps using Graph API version v2.3 or older."

Comment: `user_groups` has been deprecated. Any idea on what to use in its stead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to get the groups via graph api .

You need to get the user access token , then you can get the groups in which the user is the admin . `user_id/groups`

Scope - user_managed_groups

Hope this answers your question .
[Reference Image - Graph Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4A2R.png)