# Facebook PHP Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a script with Facebook PHP Graph SDK, The script working in following way

1. First the script fetches the group feed from one group.
2. And second script uploading all collected feed from one group to another group.

It is working fine for me with **Public Group**, But its showing error when i am going to fetch or upload feeds from **Closed Group**.

I think its a permission problem but not sure .

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Access Token for a closed group on facebook graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399333/get-access-token-for-a-closed-group-on-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: API access to closed groups has been pretty much limited to group admins; you will need to use an access token of a group admin that has granted `user_managed_groups` permission. (Of course, posting into the group would happen in that admin user’s name only then as well.)